# How to store std::list in persistence given only a pointer to buffer and size

Tags: c++, list, structure, memcpy

I wanted to copy a `std::list` into an arrays of structures. I copy from an array of structures and populate the list. It works fine, but when I do it the other way, the copy is not correct because of pointers. Tried with `operator=()` but since it is a pointer copy it does not work and then I tried `memcpy()` but it resulted in the following problem:

```
class THistory
{
public:
    UInt32          index;
    UInt32          navToID;
};

std::list<THistory>  histList;
THistory*hist2 = new THistory;
hist2->index = 1;
histList.push_back(*hist2)
```

Now, I need to do the reverse. Store `List` into `hist3`:

```
THistory*hist3 = new THistory;
std::list<THistory>::iterator histBuffer2 = CoreML::histList.begin();
memcpy(&(hist3->index),&(histBuffer2->index), sizeof(UInt32));//Corrected as per answers.
```

The reason to do this is I only have `Write()` function that takes a buffer pointer and its size to store the data in persistence as the interface. Before, I used to have an array of structures so it worked fine but now I moved to `std::list`. Unable to use the same format so copying the list into structure and trying to do the same.

I don't know if it is possible to do the same with `std::list`, pointers appreciated.

.

Comment: I would want to ask why do you want to do this , but no , so here is the answer: `memcpy(&(hist3->index),&(histBuffer2->index), sizeof(UInt32))`

Comment: Why on Earth would you `memcpy()` a simple `uint`? Also, it's better to refrain from using custom type wrappers if you can (`UInt32`), that's not portable.

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#, you don't have to create new object using `new`. In fact, if you don't do `delete hist2` you will have a memory leak.

Comment: As for your error, it's actually pretty clear, and you saying "Any *pointers* appreciated" could be seen almost as a pun, because the problem here is that [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) expects *pointers* for the first to arguments.

Comment: Thank you, actually it is a sample code... I want to do this operation to store the list in persistence. Only interface I have is via a write function that takes buffer address as input and the size. So, I store it into the structure and pass it on. I am unable to do it in List. Any Pointers will be helpful

Comment: Yes, its stupid error of judgement. Problem is bigger. Updating the question

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Damn, I wanted to write the exact same thing but you beat me to it!

Comment: I think you need to show the exact interface that you're trying to adapt to, with sample code using it, else it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.